# How to translate "And now for something completely different"?

Tags: translation, phrase-requests

The British surreal sketch comedy TV series [Monty Python's Flying Circus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Python%27s_Flying_Circus) features the catchphrase

> And now for something completely different: …

spoken by a [continuity announcer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_announcer) / [news anchorman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/News_presenter) figure to either introduce the show itself or as a transition between its sketches.

**What would be a good translation of this phrase to Esperanto?** I'm looking for a translation that is as grammatically and idiomatically correct in Esperanto as possible, while being easily re-recognizable by Esperanto speakers knowing the original English phrase.

### Context

I'd like to use this phrase somewhat out of context, namely as a title of a talk comparing Python (the programming language) to Esperanto, thus **it's important to me that the original English phrase can be recognized** in the translation by those who know it, so they'd get the reference. I assume this won't be too far-fetched as Monty Python references are quite common in the Python developer community.

### My considerations so far

#### "And now" at the beginning of a sentence

The "And now" part is *probably* straight forward:

> Kaj nun …

Though, is it permissible to start a (colloquial / spoken) sentence with *"Kaj"*? And would this, just like "And …" in English, imply that something else was said or seen before the sentence is being uttered?

#### "for"

The "for" here indicates that we / the show are heading for something (i.e. a new topic or theme), figuratively going somewhere. It could be replaced by "to" in the English phrase without altering the meaning too much. Thus, neither *"por"* (goal or beneficiary) nor *"pro"* (reason or motivation) capture the meaning correctly.

So I guess the following options remain:

1. drop it (don't represent it by an Esperanto word) and follow with nominative case (which probably indicates an implied *"estas"* / *"estos"* or *"jen"*)
2. drop it (don't represent it by an Esperanto word) and follow with accusative case (to indicate either **direction** or **direct object** of an implied action, either of which could be correct here)
3. use *"jen"* (though I think this kinda conflicts with "Kaj nun", while it also can't completely replace "Kaj nun" without losing the temporal meaning)
4. use *"al"* and follow with nominative case (because *"al"* already indicates direction and thus isn't followed by accusative case)

I feel kinda uncertain here because the English phrase isn't a "complete" sentence: It's lacking a conjugated verb. Replacing the "for", any of "here is", "comes", "follows" would work.

#### implied / absent verb

As just mentioned, the English phrase is lacking a conjugated verb. (If fact, it's doesn't contain any verb at all.) I think to preserve the tone of the phrase, this lack of verb should be retained in the Esperanto translation, if possible.

This isn't unheard of in Esperanto at all, e.g. phrases with "Jen …" don't usually contain a conjugated verb.

#### "something"

I'm unsure here whether to use

> iu

or rather

> io

or even

> ia

here. (Or, depending on the choice made for "for", the respective accusative variant "iun", "ion" or "ian".)

#### "completely"

Here, I'm pretty sure that

> tute

captures the right meaning.

#### "different"

Here, I'm unsure whether the focus should be that it's **not identical**

> malsama

or rather, that it's **not similar**

> malsimila

(or)

> diferenca

or simply that it's just something **else than** the (implied) previous topic

> alia

#### "something different"

Maybe "something different" could be translated as a single compound word, e.g.

> aliaĵo

or

> aliado

but I think bringing the "completely" aspect into this might be difficult and dropping it would change the meaning too much. Besides, this would force us to decide whether the announced "something" is an actual thing (*"-aĵ-"*) or rather some kind of process or action (*"-ad-"*) or something yet else corresponding to some Esperanto suffix, which seems like an unnecessary limitation. And I don't suppose just *"alio"* (*"ali-"* stem from *"alia"*, combined with just the *"-o"* noun ending<sup>1</sup> to make it "something") is a good, idiomatic Esperanto word.

<sup>1</sup> N.B., not the *"-io"* tablvorto ending, which cannot be used with *"ali-"*

#### word order

If staring sentences with "Kaj …" is permissible, I think the word order from the English phrase (or the order of the phrase parts discussed in the sections above) can be preserved in the Esperanto translation. I don't see any of the few word order rules Esperanto has interfering, nor do I feel the order would imply any unwanted emphasis. (Again, as a verb is missing, the respective roles of each of the phrase parts in both English and Esperanto are not entirely clear to me, so it's hard to tell whether the order even deviates from any default word order.)

### Existing translations?

As Monty Python have been (and still are) widely popular and as they've used this catchphrase not only throughout their "Flying Circus" TV series, but also as the title of [a feature film based on the series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/And_Now_for_Something_Completely_Different), it's quite possible that (more or less) official Esperanto translations of the phrase already exist, e.g. in dubs or in subtitles. If you know of any, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Kaj nun pri io tute alia.
>
> Kaj nun al tute alia temo.

The `for` sufficiently matches the usage of `pri`, though there is in English the connotation of switching the subject.

Comment: Via unua frazo ŝajnas al mi la plej proksima. Ĝi estas preskaŭ laŭlitera traduko sed sen perdo de senco. En Tekstaro mi trovis _Nun pri io tute alia!_

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it you're overanalizing it, and asking the translation to mimic way too much. Given the context, if I had to simultaneously/quickly translate that, I'd go for something like:

```
Kaj nun, tute ne rilatite, ...
```

That's spoken language, the missing bits are provided by the context:

```
Kaj nun (ni daŭrigas la aferon), en maniero nova kiu tute ne rilatas (la ĝisnunan) ...
```

Se vi preferas solvon substantivan pli ol adverban:

```
Kaj nun/jen, io(n) tute ne rilatita(n) / malsama(n)...
```

Vi povas vidi kiel aliaj lingvoj elturniĝis [ĉi tie](https://www.opensubtitles.org/en/ssearch/sublanguageid-all/idmovie-1535).

Comment: "The way I see it you're overanalizing it" Maybe I am. Though feel free to ignore "My considerations so far" and its subsections. I've only added that to show what I tried so far.

Comment: "and [you're] asking the translation to mimic way too much." Well, I'd like to use this somewhat out of context, namely as a title of a talk comparing Python (the programming language) to Esperanto, so it's important to me that the original English phrase can be recognized by those who know it, so they'd get the reference.

Comment: Sure. I was trying to be helpful, now that I read it again, I see that you could get it wrong. I did read your "considerations so far" because, if possible, I wanted my answer to take them into account. Somethings are like poetry, when translated you can only get so much of the original meaning/rythm/feeling across.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I got that you want to be helpful (and you are!). I just feared the "My considerations so far" section might distract too much from the actual question, which isn't my intention.

Comment: Mi kredas, ke substantiva solvo vere estas bezonata por ankaŭ ebligi uzi ĝin en kunteksto kiel ["And now for something completely different - a man with a tape recorder up his brother's nose."](http://www.cardinalfang.net/episodes/season_one/tape_recorder_brother.html)

Comment: @das-g I didn't consider that, that you wanted people that already know it to get the reference. You might want to add that to the question. It's a helpful piece of information. And I understand now the analytic effort you were putting into it. I didn't know the original sentence in its context, so I guess I cannot help much with this translation ;) since I have no way to know if the translation evokes the original.

Comment: Do: Kaj nun, io tute malsama - ulo ŝovas voĉregistrilon en la nazon de sia frato! :D

Answer (score 0):

Mi dirus: "Kaj nun rilate ion tute alian:"